# A ViewModel for a Contact Form in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, viewmodel

I am not new to MVC, but I am just getting started with Laravel. In ASP.NET MVC we have ViewModels which is basically a data object that we can pass to the view. The view can then use the ViewModel in whatever way it wishes.

Is there such a thing in Laravel? I want to create a ViewModel that I can pass to my contact view and have it create a form scaffold around it!

What I currently have is:

**ROUTE**

```
Route::get('/contact', array('as' => 'contact', 'uses' => 'HomeController@contact'));

Route::post('/contact', array('as' => 'contact', 'uses' => 'HomeController@postContact'));
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
<?php

class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function contact()
    {
        return View::make('contact');
    }

    public function postContact()
    {
        $formData = Input::all();

        return View::make('contact');
    }

}
```

Also, do you foresee anything wrong with my routes and controller code? In ASP.NET MVC we can have a route with exact same name as long as the verbs are different (POST / GET).

My contact form has 3 textfields (name, email and subject) and one textarea (message).

Comment: You can't have the same methods in PHP, no overloading here unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are talking about a `view/model presenter` which is another layer between your `model` and `view` and in this case you may build your own or use existing packages:

1. [ShawnMcCool/laravel-auto-presenter](https://github.com/ShawnMcCool/laravel-auto-presenter)
2. [robclancy/presenter](https://github.com/robclancy/presenter)

Also read [this article](http://culttt.com/2014/03/03/model-presenters-laravel-4/) to get the clear idea about `presenter`.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, we have view models too. You can use the view model package from github. Here's the link to the package on GitHub: [View models in Laravel](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-view-models)

You can install the package from composer by running:

```
composer require spatie/laravel-view-models
```

You can also use nwidart for better and easier management of your mvc model. nwidart gives you the feature of modules in your laravel app. More information on [nwidart](https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v2/introduction).